# Create different contracts in run-time

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-contract

I am new to solidity :)

I try to create a general contract which its attributes are known at run-time.

Suppose we have the following contract:

```
contract Product{
     string name;
     uint price;
     constrcutor(string memory _name, uint _price){
            name = _name;
            price = _price;
     }
}
```

And for the sake of simplicity I would like to create different Product contracts in the tests.

I know that I have to migrate the contract before deploy it, but really - no idea.

I try hard, excuse for me being newbie, I really have no idea how to do it or how to google it :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to create a contract for every new product, as this would be expensive in terms of gas consumption.

You can try something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

contract ManageProduct {
    
    struct Product {
        string name;
        uint256 price;
    }
    
    Product[] public products;
    
    constructor(){}
     
    function addProduct(string calldata _name, uint256 _price) external {
        products.push(Product(_name, _price));    
     }
}
```

You just need to define a structure to store the attributes of the product (name, price, etc), and then you can save every new product into an array of products through function `addProduct()`.

Then, you can add other functions to go through this array and retrieve the necessary information. Depending on your needs, you may use a mapping to add an ID for every Product and then access the mapping through the ID instead of looping through all the array.

Comment: My intension is to create a DApp which everyone can post their product, so this must be fully dynamic contract? Maybe it is hard for me to express myself ...

Comment: With my example, anyone can add as many products as needed. When you declare an array as example[], this is dynamic and it is extended as you add new elements.

Comment: Thank you, I really understand now :)